# Breeze query on related properties not working?

Tags: breeze

From the Breeze [document](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples) this should be working, but I can't make it work for me.

This is my EF code first classes:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? SectorId { get; set; }
    public Sector Sector { get; set; }
}
public class Sector
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In Breeze controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Company> Companies()
    {
        return _repository.Context.Companies.Include("Sector");
    }
```

I want to make a query like this:

```
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Companies").where("Sector.Name", "==", "Finance");
or 
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Companies").where("Sector", "any", "Name", "==", "Finance");
```

But I get this error:

> unable to locate property: Sector on type: Company

If I change to lower case,

```
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Companies").where("sector.name", "==", "Finance"); 
or
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Companies").where("sector", "any", "name", "==", "Finance");
```

I got this error:

> undefined is not a function

What's my problem? I'm using Breeze v.1.4.14.

Comment: You try to expand the sector entity in breeze...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query in your Linq:

```
 [HttpGet]
public IQueryable<dynamic> Companies()
{
    return _repository.Context.Companies.Select(a=>new
    {
      Company=a,
      Sector=a.Sector
     });
}
```

You missed the constructor in your entity now you can check it

Sector entity:

```
     public class Sector {
      public sector(){
           Companies=new Hashest<Company >();
           }

     public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies {get;set;}
      }
```

Comment: Just tried and not working. The first one gives me error `Could not find a property named 'Company' on type 'xxx.Company'.`. And the second one `unable to locate property: Sector on type: Company`. The first error is understandable, but the second one is strange. By the way, I also tried to remove include "Sector" from server which doesn't make any difference. Also, the expand("Sector") on breeze itself is working (because I could see the column shows value before I apply filter), but the where clause fails.

Comment: Hi frnd u will get the sector data dynamically u will get it

Comment: I still get the error `unable to locate property: Sector on type: Company`

Comment: Check the sector entity class

Comment: The Sector entity class is exactly as shown above except it has one more property of string type. It doesn't have back reference to Company.

Comment: So, I just tried to add Companies collection to Sector as you suggested, but still the same error.

Comment: The same error as `unable to locate property: Sector on type: Company`